# Store bindingexpression for later use

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I have an application where `IsEnabled` binding is used.
I also need to remove this binding for a short moment.

I have created an `ControlBehavior` with an attached property to use as a temporary storageplace. `ClearIsEnabledBinding` will set the binding used in this attached property. `RestoreIsEnabeldBinding` is supposed to return the binding to the original place.  This doesn't work. When the binding is cleared the attached property also is cleared.

The scenario is like this. I have a textbox with a binding for IsEnabled to the viewmodel with a converter. When I use a specific function all IsEnabled should be true regardless of the value in the viewmodel. This is easy just delete the binding and set to true. But when I return from this function I need to restore the binding to it's original binding to the viewmodel with a converter. So I need to save the entire bindingexpression somewhere and then "put" it back

My class is as follow:

Any suggestions to what I'm doing wrong?

```
public partial class ControlBehavior
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsEnabledBindingProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
         "IsEnabledBinding",
         typeof(BindingExpression),
         typeof(ControlBehavior),
         new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public static void SetIsEnabledBinding(DependencyObject element, BindingExpression value)
    {
        if (value != null)
        {
            element.SetValue(IsEnabledBindingProperty, value);
            SetIsEnabledBindingSet(element, true);
        }
    }

    public static BindingExpression GetIsEnabledBinding(DependencyObject element)
    {
        var obj = element.GetValue(IsEnabledBindingProperty);
        return (BindingExpression) obj;
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsEnabledBindingSetProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "IsEnabledBindingSet",
        typeof(bool),
        typeof(ControlBehavior),
        new PropertyMetadata(false));

    public static void SetIsEnabledBindingSet(DependencyObject element, bool value)
    {
        element.SetValue(IsEnabledBindingSetProperty, value);
    }

    public static bool GetIsEnabledBindingSet(DependencyObject element)
    {
        return (bool)element.GetValue(IsEnabledBindingSetProperty);
    }


    public static void ClearIsEnabledBinding(DependencyObject element)
    {
        SetIsEnabledBinding(element, ((Control)element).GetBindingExpression(UIElement.IsEnabledProperty));
        ((Control)element).SetBinding(UIElement.IsEnabledProperty, new Binding());
    }

    public static void RestoreIsEnabledBinding(DependencyObject element)
    {
        if (!GetIsEnabledBindingSet(element))
        {
            return;
        }
        ((Control)element).SetBinding(UIElement.IsEnabledProperty, GetIsEnabledBinding(element).ParentBindingBase);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't you use  simple triggers?

Comment: I don't want to add code to my view. Because this behavior have to work on all controls on all my views.

Comment: IsEnabledBinding &  IsEnabledBindingSet property declarations are missing that inturns calls the getproperty & setproperty.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: When you create a dependency property, you define a string for propertyName, check "IsEnabledBindingProperty" definition.

Comment: I don't see what is wrong. You mean I missed something in the declarations that prevents this from working?

Comment: check " how to define.." section in "http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/140620/WPF-Tutorial-Dependency-Property "  and compare with your declaration.

Comment: The problem is not the attached propery. The bindingexpresion stored in the attached property is just a reference and this is overwriten when a new binding is set to the isEnabaled property

Comment: As mentioned you could potentially do this with a data trigger, or you could try a multi binding. Put it into a global style if you want it applied to all instances of particular controls.

Comment: The solution you're trying (replace the binding) sounds like a workaround to a problem that probably have more straight forward solutions (as suggested - triggers, multi-binding, styles etc...). Can you describe the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: I have tried to put it in a global style and override the IsEnabled property. However the binding on the textbox is the one calling the shoots. I can't override it with a style.

Answer (score 0):

> THe scenario is like this. I have a textbox with a binding for IsEnabled to the viewmodel with a converter. When I use a specific function all IsEnabled should be true regardless of the value in the viewmodel. This is easy just delete the binding and set to true. But when I return from this function I need to restore the binding to it's original binding to the viewmodel with a converter

Instead of dealing with binding you can provide mechanism to *override* `IsEnabled` value temporarily. I assume 2 thins: 1) you are binding to something (lets call it `IsEnabled`) 2) you are making some kind of *edit* mode, which should override binding value temproarily:

```
bool _isEditMode;
public bool IsEditMode
{
    get { return _isEditMode; }
    set
    {
        _isEditMode = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsEnabled)); // update IsEnabled when IsEditMode changed
    }
}

bool _isEnabled;
public bool IsEnabled
{
    get
    {
        return IsEditMode || _isEnabled; // return true if IsEditMode == true or actual value otherwise
    }
    set
    {
        _isEnabled = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

Now if you bind

```
<TextBox IsEnable="{Binding IsEnabled, Converter= ...}" ... />
```

then as soon as you set `IsEditMode = true` textbox will become enabled. If you set `IsEditMode = false` textbox will be again enabled or disabled depending on the value of `IsEnabled` viewmodel property.

Comment: Hi.   I need to ignore the binding and override it to get a different behavior. When I'm done I have to restore the binding to restore the original behavior from the viewmodel.

Comment: Hi.  That would work if all IsEnabled are bound to the view model.  I have som views that the IsEnabled is bound to some other element in the view.  I have to find a way without changing the viewmodels or the views.

Answer (score 0):

We've used the below class to do what I think you're trying to achieve:

```
/// <summary>
/// Utilities to be used with common data binding issues
/// </summary>
class DataBindingUtils

{

    private static readonly DependencyProperty DummyProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(

          "Dummy",

          typeof(Object),

          typeof(DependencyObject),

          new UIPropertyMetadata(null));



    /// <summary>
    /// Get a binding expression source value (using the PropertyPath), from MSDN forums:
    /// "Yes, there is one (class to provide the value) inside WPF stack, but it's an internal class"
    /// Get source value of the expression by creating new expression with the same
    /// source and Path, attaching this expression to attached property of type object
    /// and finally getting the value of the attached property
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="expression"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static Object Eval(BindingExpression expression)

    {

        // The path might be null in case of expression such as: MyProperty={Binding} - in such case the value we'll get

        // will be the DataContext

        string path = null;

        if (expression.ParentBinding != null && expression.ParentBinding.Path != null)

        {

            path = expression.ParentBinding.Path.Path;

        }



        Binding binding = new Binding(path);

        binding.Source = expression.DataItem;

        DependencyObject dummyDO = new DependencyObject();

        BindingOperations.SetBinding(dummyDO, DummyProperty, binding);

        object bindingSource = dummyDO.GetValue(DummyProperty);

        BindingOperations.ClearBinding(dummyDO, DummyProperty);

        return bindingSource;

    }

}
```

Comment: Hi.  I don't need the value.  THe scenario is like this.  I have a textbox with a binding for IsEnabled to the viewmodel with a converter. When I use a specific function all IsEnabled should be true regardless of the value in the viewmodel. This is easy just delete the binding and set to true.  But when I  return from this function I need to restore the binding to it's original binding to the viewmodel with a converter. So I need to save the entire bindingexpression somewhere and then "put" it back

Comment: So this is what the method above does - it duplicates existing Binding, but does it with a "deep copy".

Comment: Does it handle Multibindings? Cause some of my bindings are multibindings.

Comment: I'm not sure - but you can probably extend it to support multi binding

Answer (score 0):

What I'm doing with a button is to store the `BindingBase` and restore it afterwards:

```cs
private async void RetryButton_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    System.Windows.Controls.Button button = (System.Windows.Controls.Button)sender;
    System.Windows.Data.BindingBase bindingBase = button.GetBindingExpression(UIElement.IsEnabledProperty).ParentBindingBase;
    button.IsEnabled = false; // This will remove the binding, which is what we want.

    await _pageViewModel.RetryAsync();

    _ = button.SetBinding(UIElement.IsEnabledProperty, bindingBase); // Add the binding back again.
}
```